# Multiple aggregates handle with one table?

Tags: domain-driven-design

we are modeling an order system and we have the Order concept. The Order has a life cycle from it is created to it is delivered and between them the order can be in other states. Some states have particular business logic, and sometimes share other business logic such as when an order can be expire in a concrete date if it has not finished on time.

Well, the team is doubting if

1. Use the state pattern (one aggregate, one repository), or
2. Use one aggregate/repository for handle each state of the order.

Within of the second approach, we are considering to use the same table for each repository, to have a table order to persist/load each aggregate. **It is well seen from DDD perspective?**

What do you think about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, DDD is all about not polluting the domain with infrastructure concerns; whether different aggregates are stored in the same table is an infrastructure concern.  As long as the repository/repositories are able to meet their obligations, go for it.

That said, having an Order have a lot of variation in terms of what operations are legal and what information is available from state to state might be a sign that the states might make sense being apportioned to different bounded contexts (e.g. a context where items are added to an order (e.g. a cart context), a checkout/payment context, an assembly for delivery context, and a being delivered context).